# Pusher auth example fails for node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, pusher

The **authentication code** example for node.js on [pusher.com](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#/lang=node) does not work.

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var Pusher = require( 'pusher' );

var app = express( express.logger() );
app.use( express.bodyParser() );

var pusher = new Pusher( { appId: APP_ID, key: APP_KEY, secret: APP_SECRET } );

app.post( '/pusher/auth', function( req, res ) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var auth = pusher.auth( socketId, channel );
  res.send( auth );
} );

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen( port );
```

I get the following error returned.  How do I resolve this?

```
TypeError: Object #<Pusher> has no method 'auth'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, for whatever reason they must have changed the method name from ***auth*** to ***authenticate***.

Here is my fixed version of their example.  Note line 4 ***pusher.authenticate***

```
app.post( '/pusher/auth', function( req, res ) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var auth = pusher.authenticate( socketId, channel );
  res.send( auth );
} );
```

Here's what I see in my ***pusher.js*** file.
Locally, in my node_modules:

```
/** Returns a signature for given socket id, channel and socket data.
 *
 * @param {String} socketId socket id
 * @param {String} channel channel name
 * @param {Object} [data] additional socket data
 * @returns {String} authentication signature
 */
Pusher.prototype.authenticate = function(socketId, channel, data) {
  return auth.getSocketSignature(this.config.token, channel, socketId, data);
};
```

Pusher.js package.json

```
{
  "name": "pusher",
  "description": "Node.js client to interact with the Pusher REST API",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "Pusher",
    "email": "support@pusher.com"
  },
```

Comment: The pusher-node-server library definitely still only has a method/function called `auth`. See https://github.com/pusher/pusher-node-server/blob/master/lib/pusher.js#L32 What Node.js package are you using?

Comment: Weird - I just did an 'npm install pusher --save' and my package.json shows "pusher": "^1.0.0".  Let me check the source in my local node modules directory.

Comment: I added the relevant code from the pusher.js file in my answer.  Am I doing something odd?  Maybe I should be using 'pusher-node-server'?

Comment: `pusher` is definitely the correct NPM module https://www.npmjs.org/package/pusher If you click-through to the github repo via the NPM page you'll see the function is definitely called `auth`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it.  I just don't know how I got the code I did via npm.  I'll check the repo history.  Maybe it was a timing thing.